# Search number of occurrence of passed keywords in a description fields in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help to search in the description fields of my table. The description is a text fields in the table which contains keywords start with the "#" and places(location) start with the "@" like below.

```
I am going to my #school. #schoollife #fun #masty @St. Xavier's High School
```

I need a keyword search in the description field. For example, I have searched with the **"school fun"**, then it will check for all the recorded and give me result for how many keywords(#school #fun) are matched in the description field with the searched text. if the description contains both the keywords(#school #fun) than it will return 2, if it contains one(either #school or #fun) then it will return 1 and if not contains any then it will return 0.

Comment: Based on the user data entry you will need to prepend the search terms "school" and "fun" with # or @ and of course add a suitable WHERE clause identifying the row of the specific description field you would like to check.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LOCATE("school", description) > 0 AND LOCATE("fun", description) > 0 THEN
                 2
            WHEN LOCATE("school", description) > 0  OR LOCATE("fun", description) > 0 THEN
                 1
            ELSE
                 0
       END  AS  occurences            
FROM my_table
```

Comment: It's not a fixed number of the word in the search text. school fun is just an example. Maybe it would be 3 or 4 or more

Comment: Then do 3 or 4 more "WHEN" clauses. What are you expecting? This is merely an SQL statement and not an application! You will need to build an application around it that generates the SQL based on the user entries you have. The search words will need to be passed into the SQL statement as variables that you would need to bind etc.